# powershell script to get output of webpage which includes javascripts for forms

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, web-scraping

I am trying to write a powershell script to read a webpage which uses javascript on it and get the output. webpage source code is something like below but the page itself in browser has a form as a result of javascripts. I need to get the form by powershell but so far not successful as Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod just get the content which refers to the js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name=robots content=noindex><link rel=icon href=/websellingbooking/favicon.ico><title>Loading</title><link rel=stylesheet href=/websellingbooking/css/custom.css nonce="nonce-GzB2v2o2sBKmQkE5xM+0cPpjQ+rO8KyK/kI1DdxAQUY=" type=text/css><link href=/websellingbooking/css/app.4975c048.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/websellingbooking/css/bulks-sellerss.67fb10ba.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/websellingbooking/js/app.0c50239a.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/websellingbooking/js/bulks-sellerss.08a611c4.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/websellingbooking/css/bulks-sellerss.67fb10ba.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/websellingbooking/css/app.4975c048.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script src=/websellingbooking/js/bulks-sellerss.08a611c4.js></script><script src=/websellingbooking/js/app.0c50239a.js></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A)** There is no HTML form in the source. If you have control over the websites, it might be an option to write complete HTML pages/templates including the form. That way, all elements are downloadable.

**B)** The Chromium browser can be used in a headless way, which means without a graphical user interface. Thus one can request a website on a server-environment and get a fully rendered snapshot of the page, as it was loaded in Chromium.
See also: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md